# Can you make Soya milk with Soya Chunks?

Tags: soymilk, recipe-changing

I want to make soya milk, like it is done in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDdzSr7RqC8) recipe. The recipe calls for soya beans, but my INDO-PAK shop sells Soya Chunks, but not the beans. Was wondering if Soya Chunks is acceptable and what variations in the recipe should be used when you use the chunks instead of the beans? Just for reference [these](https://www.spiceemporium.co.za/product/dark-soya-chunks-500g/) are the soya chunks I have my eye on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soy milk is made from grinding up soy beans and cooking them to dissolve out their fat, sugar, and protein into water. The soy juice is then nutritionally reminiscent of cow's milk.
When the soy milk is exposed to calcium or magnesium the proteins denature and make cheese-like curds (Tofu).

[TVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textured_vegetable_protein) is made by extruding defatted soy flour through a 200C nozzle that basically denatures and melts the proteins
and causes them to make a spongy protein mesh. They won't denature again- nor will they ever dissolve into liquid again.
Unfortunately, Soya Chunks can't be used to make anything like soy milk.

Soy milk is easy to make. If you can find dry soy beans you can make the milk yourself. The beans ship easily and at this point it's hard to imagine a place on earth where they can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, for pretty much the same reason that you cannot make beet juice from beet sugar. Soya "chunks" (more widely known as textured vegetable protein) are not soya beans, and cannot be used as a substitute for beans.